# Within various languages, how often are colours used to signify a condition or a feeling?

Tags: idiomaticity, colour-terms

I've seen in the English language that colors are used to signify what a person feels or a condition that person exists in (i.e. 'blue' referring to sadness and 'red' referring to anger.) I also know of a German example:

> Ich bin blau

which idiomatically translates to "I am drunk."

What other languages use colours for this purpose? Is it a common occurrence?

Comment: _[L'amour est bleu](https://youtube.com/watch?v=nD4ib9-laGY),_ according to some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Italian we say "sono al verde" when we don't have money (verde = green), and "la vedo grigia" literally I see it gray (gray = grigio) to mean something difficult to do or to realize.